# Obtaining a covid test in Czech Republic

Tags: covid-19, japan, czech-republic

Next month I'll be travelling to Czech Republic for a couple of weeks and then returning to Japan, where I live. In order to re-enter Japan I will need to have a COVID test before leaving the Czech Republic. This needs to fulfil some strict requirements:

- samples must be taken within 72 hours of my departure time
- only certain test methods are acceptable (details [here](https://www.mhlw.go.jp/content/000825144.pdf)), e.g. an antigen test is not acceptable
- I need a certificate of the results

I haven't had much luck googling how to get a COVID test in Czech republic, because the search results are all about whether I need a test before entering Czech, rather than getting a test before I leave. Are there facilities in Czech Republic where I can obtain such a test on this kind of time scale?

Answer (score 8):

I suspect it's not the only — or even the best — option, but there is [covid-19 testing available at Prague Airport](https://www.prg.aero/en/testing-covid-19). Details are very much subject to change at short notice, but, as of this writing, collection can be done by nasopharyngeal swab (acceptable to Japan) or by saliva (not acceptable to Japan), and results can be available in [48, 24, or 2 hours, depending on how much you pay](https://www.ghcgenetics.cz/covid/kestazeni/dokumenty/CENIK_PRICELIST_COVID_19.pdf). The same provider [also offers additional collection points](https://www.ghcgenetics.cz/covid/covid-en/) that may be more convenient for you than heading to the airport the day before your flight, including one at Václavské náměstí (Wenceslas Square) in central Prague.

You can also ask at your hotel if they have any ideas about other testing options; this is a common question from travelers these days.

Comment: And finally, it’s likely that the testing requirement will be dropped by the time of OPs trip.

Comment: One thing I worry about with respect to the airport option is that it says they give you the results by SMS or email. The Japanese documents say they need a certificate of results, and knowing Japanese bureaucracy I don't know if an email would count.

Comment: Oh, but the price list talks about certificates, so maybe this is an option

Answer (score 3):

The official website on this is here; https://covid.gov.cz/en/situations/testing/how-get-tested Unless you have very fancy travel insurance you are probably a "self-payer", but it's not too expensive. The prices are regulated.

Under the heading "Test Request" there are two websites for finding a test location;

- This one is for locations in Prague; https://covid.praha.eu/
- This one is for anywhere else; https://crs.uzis.cz/ (only available in Czech)

I have used these services in Prague and my experience of is was that even the regular, non-rapid versions always got back to me in under 48 hours. Still, you might want to select a provider that offers a rapid service with reservation, I see plenty of those on the list for Prague.

They will email you your test results, the email has the form;

> We are sending a confirmation of collection for PCR test.
>
> Name: [your name] Test date: [that date] Medical Testing -
> [name of test center]
> The test result will be sent directly to you by the
> laboratory.
>
> The result, including the internationally recognised certificate, can
> also be found on the Citizen's Vaccination Portal.
>
> COVIDPass team

Then they send you via sms a passowrd to log into the website and see your results.
On the website you can download a pdf (in Czech) that has the type, location, date and result of the test, alongside your details and a stamp from the test centre. It can have your passport number on too, if you give it to them wild booking the test (I didn't). So that is the certificate, if you had a printer it could be a paper certificate.